# How to show progress bar based on gridview data fill?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

**Show a progress bar based on gridview data fill**

How to show a progress bar based on gridview data fill?

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried so far? Also please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with your **ASPX** page, I hope you are understanding and helpful for you.

```
private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        progressBar.Visible = true;
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        System.Threading.Thread thread = 
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(loadTable));
        thread.Start();
}

private void loadTable()
{
        // Load your Table...
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SDA.Fill(table);
        setDataSource(table);
}

internal delegate void SetDataSourceDelegate(DataTable table);
private void setDataSource(DataTable table)
{
        // Invoke method if required:
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new SetDataSourceDelegate(setDataSource), table);
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = table;
            progressBar.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Put the method loading the data into another thread and set the datasource when it's finished. There should be an invoke required. If you want to show percentage values in the progressbar, don't use the style 'Marquee' and add another function and delegate you can invoke for setting the value of the progress bar.

If binding the data to the grid is the problem, then you can not put the binding into another thread and you may show a progress-popup that runs in another thread.

Comment: How will this work for  a asp.net page? Your button code occurs after the post back- and then you set visible = true - and then load - all of that code will run during the one postback without the browser updating. Are we missing some code, like say a elephant in the room?

Comment: You need to use with update panel with button by using UseSubmitBehavior="false" you can disable postbacks of onclick

Comment: Hum, ok. There is not a native asp.net progress bar. What kind of control is being used here? (or is this a named div?).